# spring-boot-devtools doesn't reload dependent modules in multi-module maven project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

Before I start, I'd like to say that I already tried the solution proposed in [spring-boot-devtools reload of multi-module maven project changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998251/spring-boot-devtools-reload-of-multi-module-maven-project-changes), which didn't work for me.

**Problem:**

I have a multi-module Spring Boot project of this sort:

[image]

The module **launcher** has a Maven dependency on module **GUI**. I launch my Spring Boot application from the main method in **launcher**.

When I run the application and change any HTML file in **GUI** module, the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency doesn't do a live reload of these changes for my running application. Not even manual restart of **launcher** helps. I need to compile **GUI** manually and then run **launcher** again.

**What I tried:**

1. I tried defining the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency first in
   **parent** `pom.xml`, then in **GUI** module only and then in both at the same time.
2. I tried adding `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=../gui` in my `application.properties` file as suggested in [spring-boot-devtools reload of multi-module maven project changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998251/spring-boot-devtools-reload-of-multi-module-maven-project-changes). This does indeed trigger the reload (according to the log), but those changes just don't propagate to the `jar` file of **GUI** dependency. Also, before I even made this project into multi-module, there was no need for reloading just because of HTML files (nothing is being compiled) and I could see the changes right away.

I use Netbeans GUI if that's of any help. I also tried running the project from command line, with no success. The Maven packaging on all modules is set to `jar`.

Comment: what happens if you remove relative paths from the equation and only configure `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=` with absolute paths?

Comment: @BrianClozel It works this way. I put in the path is this format: `C:\\Users\\Saraph\\path\\to\\gui`. However I'd still want to generalize this somehow. While it works for my machine, every single team member would have to reconfigure this.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have no idea how it happened, but upon one revisit it started working without me knowingly changing anything. It doesn't even require the `spring.devtools.restart.additional-path` property set.

Could've been a problem of Netbeans IDE perhaps? Then again, it didn't work from command line either. If anyone has any explanation for this, it'd still be grateful as it may prevent this problem from happening in future.

Comment: I'm glad your problem resolved itself, but it's hard to characterize this as an *answer*.

Comment: @MikePatrick I understand, but I can't offer anything better. The answer is "if this happens to you, try to reload your development environment".

Answer (score 5):

The fact that this works when you configure absolute paths in devtools tells me that this is mainly a work directory issue.

So this means that:

- configured paths should be relative to where you launch the CLI
- you should configure the same location as a work directory in the run configuration of your IDE (whatever configuration your IDE is using to launch your application should have such an option)

In your case: everything should be relative to your launcher module; this should be as well your work directory in your IDE.

Comment: Please see my own answer. Thanks for help, but I'll have to mark my own as a solution this time.